# Start an activity from background service in Android 10 or higher

Tags: android, flutter, performance, android-service

I'm developing an application that works like ***App Lock***. But my application has some differences. My app has a **MainActivity** will run as **Home and Default** app.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Beside that, I have a **background service** will listen another app is using on foreground (top of stack).

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

/**
 * Check running apps
 * @return Package is running
 */
private String checkRunningApps() {
    String packageName = "";
    UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService("usagestats");
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long beginTime = endTime - 10000;
    UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
    UsageEvents usageEvents = usm.queryEvents(beginTime, endTime);
    while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
        usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
        if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
            packageName = event.getPackageName() == null ? "" : event.getPackageName();
        }
    }
    Log.d("flutter", "Target package: " + packageName);
    return this.allowPackages.contains(packageName) ? "" : packageName;
}
```

**MainActivity** will *bind and listen* a callback from **background service**. When service has a callback, **MainActivity** launches an activity to authenticate the user

```
@Override
public void onCredential(String currentPackage) {
    Log.d("flutter", "onCredential " + currentPackage);
    if (BiometricUtil.doesDeviceHasSecuritySetup(this) && !currentPackage.isEmpty()){
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.mAppLockService).setIsAuthenticate(
                AppLockService.generateCredential(
                        "Authenticate",
                        AppLockService.AUTHENTICATE_VALUE_FAIL
                )
        );
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceCredentialActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppLockService.PACKAGE_KEY, currentPackage);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTargetPackage(String targetPackage) {
    Log.d("flutter", "onStartTargetPackage " + targetPackage);
    Intent launchIntent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(targetPackage);
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}
```

So, everything is good on Android 9 or lower, but Android 10 or higher, I have some problems. The problems are:

1. android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" and android:launchMode="singleInstance" didn't work.
2. When MainActivity in background and start a new Activity, sometime it appears on Top of stack, sometime it just appears above MainActivity and another app like Settings is appears on Top of stack.

So I don't know why this happened. If you know the reason, please give me an answer.

***Here is my demo about my problem.***

1. [Correct on Android 9](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D8Rbj8_ZuJUIzhQRqpmbQcszFI1Pxsfb/view?usp=sharing)
2. [Incorrect on Android 10](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NN-0Nj1GWmTfJpagzQQccSCZC7sedClU/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Do you have other activities in your app? Do you set `android:taskAffinity` for those activities in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have another activity is DeviceCredentialActivity but I just set theme to it.

Comment: You've defined `MainActivity` as `singleInstance`. When you launch `DeviceCredentialActivity` this should go into a different task. Can you verify that this is happening? Use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` where you can see the list of tasks and the activities that they contain. Try this on both older Android and newer versions (where you are having problems)

Comment: If you are doing this correctly, you should never have any other activities in the task with `MainActivity`, so that `clearTaskOnLaunch` should not be needed.

Comment: Well, I see. Thank you so much for your explanation to my first problem about `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" and android:launchMode="singleInstance" didn't work.` @DavidWasser. Can you help me for the second problem, sir? I added 2 demos on my post, sir.

Comment: Did you check? Was the second `Activity` launched into the same task as `MainActivity` or into another task? I'm curious what you found.